# Convert SQL query to Query builder Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder

I want to convert this SQL query to Query builder Laravel

```
SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY (titre LIKE '%book%') DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**
Try the following code:

```
DB::table('articles')->orderBy(DB::raw("title LIKE '%$value%'"),'desc')->get();
```

I think the following one also solves your problem:

```
DB::table('articles')->orderByRaw("(title LIKE '%book%') DESC")->get();
```

Comment: great, with variable : orderBy(DB::raw("title LIKE '%$value%'"),'desc') thanks

Comment: Thanks. If it works, please accept it as correct answer.

Comment: pls, how do I do to add a second field 'description' : DB::table('articles')->orderByRaw("(title, description LIKE '%book%') DESC")->get(); not work!

Comment: You may use multiple orderBy functions as below:
DB::table('articles')->orderByRaw("(title LIKE '%book%') DESC, (description LIKE '%book%')  DESC")->get();

Comment: I fixed the problem, it had another table with the description field, so i have to add the name of the table with the description field : articles.description   thanks again

Comment: It's okay. Thanks.